# img tag without src attribute but with class attribute gives a random display

Tags: html, css

I just come across one question in stackoverflow where user want to give an icon in html, but not using

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
```

but, using class like

```
<img class="iconClass">
```

And css class is

```
.iconClass{
              background:url('smiley.gif')!important;
          }
```

I tried this, but this works for me, but wierd thing is that, the image is getting repeated till the width and height specified. Why this is happening, and how to solve it?

[image: Image output]

Comment: This is expected behavior. Use `background-repeat: no-repeat`.

Comment: Yes... solved the problem. Do not know, how i missed it

Comment: You shouldn't have an img without an src in the first place. Otherwise, what's the point?

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes. I will avoid using this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

background repeat is by default set to repeat. You should set:

```
.iconClass{
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

or :

```
.iconClass{
              background:url('smiley.gif')!important no-repeat;
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it happens is because background is a composite property which includes background-color, background-image, background-repeat, background-position, background-attachment. It means that when you set background alone without specifying background-repeat you simply overwrite previously defined rule, it just falls back to default value which is repeat. To fix it you should explicitly provide it:

```
.iconClass{
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```