# Menu Hover Not showing as what i wanted it to be

Tags: html, css

Good day everyone, I created a vertical menu I already got the menu working but im really having problem in terms of the hover. Here is the picture of my main menu

**[LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC5cs.jpg)**

I want everytime I hover the same arrow will show on the other menu item. But every time I hover this is what I get

[**imgur.com/jd9hz50**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gnqU.jpg)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-3 column mainbody1 otherpagesfixer" id="wnav">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="active">menu 1</a><img class="ef1" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/img/menu2.png">
      </l1>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">menu 1</a>
      </l1>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">menu 1</a>
      </l1>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">menu 1</a>
      </l1>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#wnav ul{
  background-color: #efefef;
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left center , white, #e6e6e6);;
}
#wnav li a{
  color:blue;
}
#wnav li a:hover{
  background-image:url('img/menu2.png');
}
```

Comment: Explained more about here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453066/img-tag-without-src-attribute-but-with-class-attribute-gives-a-random-display/24453237#24453237

Comment: I already found a solution thank you everyone for answering. 

When I used the no-repeat i don't get the right output that i want instead I used the follow

    #wnav li a:hover{
      background-image:url('img/menu2.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
       height: 42px;
        left: -20px;
        top: 0;
    }

the output that i want every time I hover is this one

[http://imgur.com/BQAvOLO][1]


  [1]: http://imgur.com/BQAvOLO

Answer (score 3):

Use `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Also take a look here: [background-repeat Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp)

`no-repeat: The background-image will not be repeated`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

**CSS:**

```
#wnav li a:hover{
  background:url('img/menu2.png') no-repeat left top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
#wnav li a:hover{
  background-image:url('img/menu2.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And your list item closing tags are wrong. they should be `</li>` instead of `</l1>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-3 column mainbody1 otherpagesfixer" id="wnav">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="active">menu 1</a><img class="ef1" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/img/menu2.png">
      </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">menu 1</a>
      </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">menu 1</a>
      </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">menu 1</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wnav ul{
  background-color: #efefef;
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left center , white, #e6e6e6);;
}
#wnav li a{
  color:blue;
}
#wnav li a:hover{
  background-image:url('img/menu2.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}
```