# Title tag text shows up on image in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, tags

I have a title tag around an image which is only supposed to show on hover. It works in IE but in chrome the title tag text is actually shown on the image as well as on hover.

Here is my html snip for that section

```
<img id="projects" title="Some of My Projects." />
```

The image is in a table but I'm not sure if that is what would be affecting this. I do have a picture of what is happening but not enough reputation to post it in my question apparently.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: check your image url (you forgot src in img tag)                                                                                                         <img src="image.jpg" alt="Some of My Projects." height="42" width="42" title="Some of My Projects.>

Comment: @ShakirKhan

I forgot to mention that I have css which handles that part.

#projects {
    
    background-image: url( "Projects_Button.png" ) ;
    width: 500px ;
    height: 300px ;
    
}

Comment: then use alt tag instead of title tag and add in your css background-repeat: no-repeat;

Comment: or check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453066/img-tag-without-src-attribute-but-with-class-attribute-gives-a-random-display

Comment: I tried the alt tag instead of title and still the same thing happened. I didnt think the background was the reason for whats happening but I tried the no-repeat anyway and the text is still shown on the image.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that setting the background-image using CSS without setting a "src" attribute apparently makes Chrome treat the image as though it didn't load, so it will display the alt or title text on top of the background image.  Setting a src attribute on the image instead of using the background-image in CSS made it stop showing the text.

Comment: Thank you brakiton, I will test that when I get home and update.

Comment: Chrome also displays the title text when there is a src attribute but the image fails to load (e.g., 404 not found).  Firefox doesn't display the title text until you mouseover, no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this as well, adding a `title` attribute on an `img` tag that lacks the `src` attribute, instead where one would use a sprite map via a `background-image` instead leads to the image showing as broken on Chrome (but works on IE).

My solution: wrap it in a span that applies the title:

`<span title="Some of My Projects."><img id="projects" /></span>`